# Postgres Recursion across 2 alternating fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a simple table:

```
table USAGE_LOG:

USAGE_ID
PC_ID
MEMORY_STICK_ID
```

So each usage entry represents a PC being used with a specific memory stick.

Both PC and memory stick ID link to a device table where device_type is 1 for PC and 2 for memory sticks.

My scenario is that I have identified a virus on some PC's, and I now need to trace all possible infected machines using my USAGE_LOG table.

My PC's are marked as having a virus in a separate table:

```
table VIRUS:

PC_ID
VIRUS_ID
```

I need to create a CTE (or view) that holds a list of all possibly infected device by recursively searching for each memory stick connected to my infected PC, I then need to find each PC connected to each of my suspect memory sticks, and subsequently each PC etc. etc.

The restrictions are that I cannot change my data structure, and I can't create any functions or stored procedures.

Is this possible, and if so how is it done?

Comment: I assume, the usage_id can be taken as the order in which things happend?

Comment: There's no need to worry about a time line, just a list of possible matches.

Comment: If you find a virus on an USB stick, the time line is the crucial element, isn't it? Or do we have to assume that any of the listed connections can happen repeatedly at any time?

Comment: The usage log shows all historical interactions between the PC's and Memory Sticks. When I find a virus I have no way of knowing where is came from or how long it's been there so I need a full network of all potentially infected devices.

Answer (score 1):

#### Test setup

I include my test setup for those who want to check it out themselves:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE usage_log (
  usage_id int primary key
, pc_id  int
, memory_stick_id int);
INSERT INTO usage_log VALUES
  (1,1,2)
, (2,3,2)
, (3,3,4)
, (4,5,4)
, (5,5,6)
, (6,7,6)
, (7,9,8)
, (8,9,10)
, (9,3,12)
, (10,11,12)
, (11,11,13);

CREATE TEMP TABLE virus(
  pc_id int
, virus_id int);
INSERT INTO virus values
  (3, 4)
, (3, 5)
, (5, 6)

/* Alternative test:
TRUNCATE VIRUS;
INSERT INTO virus values
  (9, 4)
, (9, 5);
*/
```

#### Query with two recursive CTE

This query should find all PCs and USB sticks possibly infected by internal usage recursively:

```
WITH RECURSIVE v_start AS (
    SELECT pc_id, max(u.usage_id) AS usage_id
    FROM   virus v
    JOIN   usage_log u USING (pc_id)
    GROUP  BY 1
    ),

    v_down AS (
    SELECT u.*
    FROM   usage_log u
    JOIN   v_start v USING (usage_id)

    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT u.*
    FROM   usage_log u 
    JOIN   v_down v ON u.pc_id = v.pc_id OR u.memory_stick_id = v.memory_stick_id
    WHERE  u.usage_id < v.usage_id
    ),

    v_up AS (
    SELECT u.*
    FROM   usage_log u
    JOIN   v_down v USING (usage_id)

    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT u.*
    FROM   usage_log u 
    JOIN   v_up v ON u.pc_id = v.pc_id OR u.memory_stick_id = v.memory_stick_id
    WHERE  u.usage_id > v.usage_id
    )

SELECT pc_id, 1 AS device_type            -- PCs
FROM   v_up
GROUP  BY 1

UNION ALL
SELECT memory_stick_id, 2 AS device_type  -- USB-sticks
FROM   v_up
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2, 1
```

#### Explain Query

- I assume `usage_id` is a serial column that reflects a timeline.
- **Edit:** in the first CTE `v_start` I find the **latest** log entry for every infected PC. The kind of virus is ignored completely. In my first version I had the earliest usage `min(usage_id)`, but that was before I improved the query to include all precursors, and *then* let it spread along the timeline. We have to start with the latest usage now, which will include even more suspects. We could narrow the search down if we had more information to work with.
- The first CTE is also `RECURSIVE` because, technically, you can only use one kind of CTE at once. Without the `UNION` part it is effectively a **plain CTE**. More in the manual about the [WITH clause (CTE)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html).
- In the following two CTEs I work my way back in time and then forward again to find any USB-stick *or* PC that may have made contact. **Chronological order** is relevant. See explanation below.
  Note that I use **`UNION`** - instead of `UNION ALL` in my first draft. It should be much more effective to eliminate duplicates with every step.
- The final `SELECT` is a poor man's pivot table function while at the same time removing any duplicates among PCs and USB-sticks. Both lists are put together with `UNION ALL` in this case. The final result is ordered by device type and device ID.

#### Explain strategy

**Worst case scenario** is what we have to assume and that means the PC could have been infected during *any* use.

We need to mushroom **back** (`v_down`) from the **latest** use to include any and all devices the virus could have come from.

Then, from all suspect rows, we mushroom **forward** (`v_up`) through time again, to find any and all devices that might have been infected in addition.

Voilá: all PCs and USB-sticks that may be involved.

---

#### Explain by example

Consider this setup:

```
INSERT INTO usage_log VALUES
  (1,1,2)  -- PC 1 connects to stick 3
, (3,3,4)  -- PC 3 connects to stick 4
, (2,3,2)  -- PC 3 connects to stick 2
, (2,3,6); -- PC 3 connects to stick 6
```

Here, stick 4 **never** gets in contact with USB 2, proxy or not. But they would be connected if we'd ignore the timeline.
Stick 6 connects to stick 2 by proxy because it connects to PC 3 *after* it made contact to stick 2.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to search up and down in separate tables? Would I have to do something similar to also run a separate query for suspect memory sticks? What I'm hoping for is a CTE that contains 2 columns: DEVICE_TYPE,DEVICE_ID

Comment: @GlenLamb: Actually, my first draft was still not pessimistic enough. See my amended answer with an explanation for the chosen strategy. Also I list both device types now together

Comment: I still don't understand the need for the up AND down tables. IF you remove the "where u.usage_id < v.usage_id" from v_up can't V_down be done away with?

Comment: @GlenLamb: Try it an you will see, that you get endless loops. Also, the result would be logically wrong. Take a piece of paper and make a diagram. The proliferation is one-way along the timeline. A device can only infect another one **after** it has been infected.

Comment: @GlenLamb: I found and fixed a mistake that resulted from my upgrade to the second version.

Comment: OK, so what if I do want the entire connection network regardless of id order? What I'm really after is a way to find all connections ever made given an initial list of starting points that could contain both PC's and Sticks. Ignore the logic of the scenario, that's was purely a mechanism to explain the problem I'm having.

Comment: On second thoughts, let's add a flag in to Device to say that this device is a starting point and from there I want all devices ever connected to them physically or by proxy.

Comment: @GlenLamb: The timeline still applies. I added more explanation. If you have defined starting points, you can purge `v_start` and `v_down` and only need the CTE `v_up`.

Comment: I don't really understand your point in the example, is there a typo there?

Regardless, the CTE I'm trying to create should give me: PC 3, and Stick 2,4,6 because they form a connection network that's what i'm after. Just because I have only just discovered the virus doesn't mean it's just appeared, it could have come from any connected device at any point. So I do want everything.

Comment: @GlenLamb: There is no typo in my example. Proliferation can not travel back and forth in time. The timeline is crucial for a correct answer. I believe my answer to be correct. I don't feel inclined to assist with a wrong one. Good luck!

Comment: @EriwnBrandstetter There is no timeline, i'm not interested in a timeline, you have not solved the problem I face, which is to create a CTE that contains all devices involved in a network of connectivity between them. Part of my question was "is this possible" is the answer simply "no"?

You cannot tell me that my question is wrong, you're answer must be wrong, it does not solve the problem posed in the question.